# Is it possible to use ram of an inactive VM on another VM?

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine

I'm basically looking at running Ubuntu as the host and having two VMs (2 Guest OS's, each on different VM). The two VMs will be running Windows 7 and another distro of Linux.

My computer comes with only 6 GBs of Ram. I was wondering is it possible to have 3 Gbs for my Ubuntu and allocate 3 GBs to Windows 7 and 3 GBS to the other distro of Linux and I will only use one VM at a time.

Basically what I'm asking is that can I use the Ram from the inactive (Turned off) VM (Windows 7) to use/run/operate the VM with the Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of RAM you set in the VM options is just a number until you start the VM, so yes this will be possible

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct, until you fire up a VM the allocated memory isn't used by the VM.

Just be careful you don't fire up the second VM with one already running, as that will immediately allocate all the remaining RAM available on your machine and it will hang/crash/become unusable.

However, unless you're using your VMs for something heavy duty, Windows 7 probably won't need more than 2GB and Linux can mostly run on 1GB or less (depending on desktop environment if you're using one, if it's headless then you can get away with less).